# In C++, why does calling a function on a nested unordered_map necessitate a move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have a nested unordered map that holds a custom object in C++ 11. It looks similar to this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, CustomClass>>
```

This custom class does not have a move constructor and cannot have an implicit one. I am getting an error when trying to assign into this structure:

```
storageStruct[string_1][string_2].function(parameter);
```

The actual error chain explanation is really long due to it going into the templates, but this is the one I feel is most applicable:

**Candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided**

I am not intending to move this object but simply call its member function. How do I avoid this unnecessary move?

Comment: Does `CustomClass` have a default constructor?

Answer (score 5):

`std::unordered_map::operator[]` needs to create an element out of nothing if there is none for the key you request, ie the values need to be default constructible. A move constructor would be just one candidate. Either supply a default constructor or dont use `operator[]` (you can use `unordered_map::find` to find elements and `unordered_map::insert` to insert elements).

Answer (score 2):

It's not trying to move anything. Specific member functions of templates can require extra behaviours in their template parameter types. The use of [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) requires that the enclosed type is [`DefaultConstructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible), because it is specified to create an element if one is not present.

If you are sure that `string_1` and `string_2` are present, then you change from `operator[]` to [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at). This throws [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range), rather than creating an element, so it doesn't require the held type be `DefaultConstructible`. It also has a `const` overload, whereas `operator[]` does not.

If you don't want the possibility of throwing (maybe you are not sure the strings are present) then you can use `find`, as the other answers explain.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I avoid this unnecessary move?

`std::unordered_map::operator[]` mutates container (inserts an empty element if it does not exists), so you should use read only interface for that:

```
 auto f1 = storageStruct.find( string_1 );
 if( f1 != storageStruct.end() ) {
     auto f2 = f1->second.find( string_2 );
     if( f2 != f1->second.end() )
         f2->second.function( parameter );
 }
```